# produce dataframe of Count no. of sheets in all workbooks in a directory

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

```
path =r"C:\Users\Ayush\Desktop\New folder"

filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
print('File names:', filenames)

xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\Ayush\\Desktop\\New folder\\1.xlsx')
res = len(xl.sheet_names)
print(res)

for file in filenames
xl1 = pd.ExcelFile(filenames)
res = len(xl1.sheet_names)
print(res)
```

Comment: i am very new to python

Comment: Explain the problem(s) you have and show the code properly formatted in the question. How is this related to VBA?

Comment: I have a directory where there are 100+ Excel files and each file has around 100+ tabs and i want to get  number of tabs in each file in a dataframe. all files will be in same directory

Comment: path =r"C:\Users\Ayush\Desktop\New folder"

filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
print('File names:', filenames)

xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\Ayush\\Desktop\\New folder\\1.xlsx')
res = len(xl.sheet_names)
print(res)

"Code till here gives me a list of all excel file and just gives number of tabs in 1.xlsx, i want this to be iterated for all files in this folder and publish that in a dataframe"

for file in filenames
xl1 = pd.ExcelFile(filenames)
res = len(xl1.sheet_names)
print(res)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = r"C:\Users"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

filename, cnt, sheets = [],[],[]
for file in onlyfiles:
    if ".xlsx" in file:
        df = pd.ExcelFile(mypath+"\\"+file)
        filename.append(file)
        cnt.append(len(df.sheet_names))
        sheets.append(df.sheet_names)
df_final = pd.DataFrame({"filename":filename,"sheets cnt":cnt,"sheets name":sheets})
```

Hope this helps...